# Pop up in Eclipse does not show Application

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Today i installed Window Builder in Eclipse Juno & after Restarting I found so many errors in HTML & jsp & then i observed that JSP files are not opening in their JSP Editor. I tried but its opening in Plain text Editor. 
Another problem came, that When in webProject i right Clicked to add new page/servlet/jsp/html... I found No Application as i showed in Screenshot

[SCREEN SHOT OF PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yh9K.jpg)

I uninstalled every Plugins that i installed earlier but even then i am facing same Error

Comment: Hah! Who knows, its just a Juno... I had similar problem after installing WB on Juno... I recommend to go back to Indigo as soon as possible. Btw, as a sidenote: Do not open connection to database in your JSP. :)

Comment: Is it Juno for J2EE? It looks like it "lost" the plugin since there is no icon on perspective buttons. Please check on installed plugins list whether the J2EE feature is loaded. If there is no such feature please get the log from workspace -> .metadata and we look for unusual errors there. You can reinstall the J2EE Feature if it's corrupted too

Comment: If you need any help according to search for cause of that problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks to All of You Guys !! But What is my Mistake that causes such thing?

Comment: That may be not your mistake but rather some bug in Juno. Juno is known to be unstable, I find Kepler more stable than Juno :)

Comment: But now i am using Helios. What about That??

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run the eclipse with clean command. Using the -clean command line argument when starting up eclipse can correct problems related to stale plugin cache information (usually shown in the log as problems loading bundles). Here is how you can add the clean command:

On windows: 
Right click on eclipse.exe -> Go to Properties -> Under target section add -clean after eclipse.exe(eclipse.exe -clean). Apply and restart eclipse.

Comment: Are u talking about properties of Shortcut of Eclipse??

Comment: Yes shortcut of eclipse. Let me know if it resolves your problem

Comment: Then juned It is not Working, Error is Coming that Path Specified in Target Box is Invalid